Raster from rasterize() in R shows different values from polygon, values don't plot as expected
I am trying to rasterize a polygon so that I can perform some zonal statistics (namely, get average values of a variable using a buffer around a point). I'd like it to be at ~100m resolution but a lower resolution is fine. I realize that changing the resolution can change the values of a raster, but I'm wondering how I can manipulate the raster to keep cell values as close as possible to the polygon I'm using. Aside from the values being incorrect, the raster behaves in unexpected ways -- when I crop it to my buffer extent and try to extract a mean value using extract() or exact_extract(), the values I get don't match up at all with the values I see when plotting the raster with the buffer. I tried to create a reproducible example but I can't recreate either issue with the data I generated, which makes me think that it has to do with how I am creating the raster.
Here's the code I'm using:

template <- rast(vect(sf_data), resolution=100, crs="EPSG:32610") # sf_data is also in this projection
raster <- terra::rasterize(vect(sf_data), template, field = "Variable")

sf_data is a polygon layer (see below). The raster itself looks fine, but the values I'm getting are a lot higher than they should be. I've played around with the resolution (and left it out) and the values are never close to the actual values in sf_data. When I run minmax() the highest value is 518, but the highest value in my polygon data is ~48.

Here's what sf_data looks like.

A portion of raster cropped to a 500m buffer. R says the average value of this using exact_extract is 203.
Here's the code for the extraction value:
site_index <- 10
pt <- sites[site_index, ]
buffer_radius <- 500
buff_terra <- vect(pt) %>% terra::buffer(width = buffer_radius) 

# crop and mask the raster 
rast_cropped <- crop(raster, buff_terra, snap = "out")

# extract values and compute mean
extracted_value <- exact_extract(rast_cropped, st_as_sf(buff_terra), fun = "mean", 
                                 weights = "area")
# also tried: 
extracted_value <- terra::extract(rast_cropped, vect(buff_terra), fun = "mean")



Judging by the plots above, one is EPSG:4326, they other may be EPSG:32610, what does crs( say for each?

Also: according your plot, your vector has the attribute variable while you're rasterizeing an attribute Variable (note capitalisation). Is your example put together from different attempts (=versions of sf_data)?

Chris-- I think this is because I plotted sf_data with ggplot2, which shows lat/long unless it's coerced to show easting/northing with datum(). I just double-checked and st_crs(sf_data) == st_crs(raster).
I-O -- sorry about that,, this was an issue with me renaming the variables to post here. I used the same variable from sf_data to rasterize.
